# (Asm\C\Drivers) Interrupt Descriptor Table on x64 Vista

Tags: assembly, driver, masm, bsod

Is there any way to save\load Interrupt Descriptor Table on x64 Vista SP2 (AMD64) without Blue Screen? Here is my code in MASM that makes Blue Screen:

```
IDTINFO struct
    word idtLimit       ?
    dword lowIDTBase    ?
    dword highIDTBase   ?
IDTINFO ends

getInterruptDescriptorTable proto :DWORD

.code
    getInterruptDescriptorTable PROC idtInfo_arg:DWORD
        local idtInfo_locl :IDTINFO

        sidt idtInfo_locl
        lea eax, idtInfo_locl
        push [eax]
        mov eax, idtInfo_arg
        pop [eax]
    getInterruptDescriptorTable endp
end
```

Well, I'm new at Assembly language, so there can be some obvious mistakes.

EDIT
This is how prototype in .h file looks like:

```
extern void getInterruptDescriptorTable(IDTINFO*);
```

Here, call in .c file:

```
IDTINFO idtInfo = {0};
getInterruptDescriptorTable(&idtInfo);
```

IDTINFO structure in C:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short idtLimit;
    unsigned int lowIDTBase;
    unsigned int highIDTBase;
} IDTINFO;
```

Comment: also, shouldn't there be a 'ret' at the end of the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x64 systems are protected by patch guard mechanism. You can`t path idt without bsod: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Patch_Protection

Answer (score 1):

More than likely it's an issue with declaring `idtInfo_arg` as a `DWORD` - because you're in 64-bit mode, you will need to change these to `QWORD`, and use `rax` instead of `eax`.

Could you perhaps post the code which calls your function?